# If statement works on Python 2 but not on python 3

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt

I have this as part of an MQTT message receiver, and I'm trying to port the code to Python 3, the problem is with some if,else statements, they do absolutely nothing on Python 3, for example this one,

```
if message.topic == "ledDoorSW_mqtt":
    if str(message.payload) == "1":
        device.setPinHigh(13)
    elif str(message.payload) == "0":
        device.setPinLow(13)
```

I understand there are fundamental differences on how each version treat strings but couldn't find out why this is the case here.

any help is appreciated!!..
thanks..

Comment: Those are actually controlled by me, in other parts of the code, I decide what strings should be the topic and the payload.

Comment: Add the output of `print(message.topic) ; print(type(message.topic)) ; print(message.payload) ; print(type(message.payload))` (exactly before the first `if` and in Python 3, where this code is supposedly not working as expected) to your question.

Comment: My guess is that `message.payload` is a `bytes` object in Python 3 and just a `str` in Python 2. If that’s the case, you would need to `decode()` it first in Python 3.

Comment: print(message.topic) >               ledDoorSW_mqtt
print(type(message.topic)) >     <class 'str'>
print(message.payload) >          b'0'
print(type(message.payload))> <class 'bytes'>

Comment: As I said, you need to do `message.payload.decode()` in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "poke" and "DeepSpace" the solution is to write

```
message.payload.decode()
```

as the payload is byte and not string.